# Why is the boundary of friends-of-friends (FOF) halo corresponding to iso-density contour?

Tags: cosmology, computational-physics, algorithms

The friends-of-friends algorithm (hereafter FOF) is commonly used to find halos in cosmological simulations. (For more information, please refer to [here](http://swift.dur.ac.uk/docs/FriendsOfFriends/algorithm_description.html) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9333084/))

I found that some literature argues that the boundary of the FOF halo is corresponding to an iso-density surface. For example, [Springel et al 2001](https://academic.oup.com/mnras/article/328/3/726/1241140?login=true) states

> It places any two particles with a separation less than some linking length $b$ into the same group. In this way, particle groups are formed that correspond to regions approximately enclosed by
> isodensity contours with threshold value $\rho\propto1/b^3$.

[More et al 2011](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/0067-0049/195/1/4/meta) says

> One could expect that for a given value of $b$, the FOF algorithm defines the boundary of a halo as corresponding to a certain isodensity surface, at least in the limit of large number of particles.

However, I can't understand the connection between the boundary of the FOF group of particles and iso-density contour. How to derive this connection in formula form? Does this connection need other hypotheses?